# Background won't display

Tags: html, css, image, background

So I've took a project from codepen.io and modified it. But now I'm trying to add a background image and I can't display it... Here's my code:

```css
body {
  background-image: url("starwars.jpg");
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-attachment: fixed;
}

div.window {
  color: white;
  width: 500px;
  padding: .42rem;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background: #26466D;
  margin: 1rem;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: BlueHighway, Arial Black, sans-serif;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
div.window label {
  display: block;
  background: #660b0b;
  font-size: larger;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: .6rem;
  transition: .4s all linear;
}
div.window label:hover {
  cursor: pointer; background: #311;
}
input.toggle ~ div {
  height: 0px; margin: .2rem;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: .6s all cubic-bezier(0.730, -0.485, 0.145, 1.620)
}
input.toggle:checked ~ div { height: 230px; }
input.toggle:checked + label { background: red; }
input.toggle { display: none; }
```

```html
<div style="height: 240px; padding-top: 1.2rem">
<div class="window">
<input type="checkbox" id="punch" class="toggle">
  <label for="punch">Use the Force, Luke.</label>
  <div>
    <img src="http://images.sequart.org/images/Star-Wars-still-use-the-force-luke-e1415132076759.jpg" style="max-width:100%;height:auto" alt="Ackbar">
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

If someone could find out why my background image is not displaying, that would be great! 
Thanks.

Comment: In your CSS you apply a background image to the `body`, but in the HTML you post as the potential problem, you have no body tag...

Answer (score 2):

I just tested your code and it works fine so I think what's happening is that the path of your background picture is wrong.

If your starwars image is not in the root folder with your html page then it cannot be `url("starwars.jpg");`. Check if you didn't put it in another folder or so.

Comment: Yes, on Codepen. I just picked the url of a random picture on google, replace it in the `background-image: url("...");` and that's it.

Comment: Just replaced the "starwars.jpg" to the url of the image. Works fine! Thanks for responding!

Answer (score 0):

Is the image "starwars.jpg" in the same folder as the .html file that is using it?

Comment: Just replaced the "starwars.jpg" to the url of the image. Works fine! Thanks for responding!